# Rotate multiple PCB designators in Altium?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, layout

I am copying rooms in a PCB from the right side of a board to the left. Rotating everything in the room is easy - select the objects, `Edit > Move > Rotate Selection`.

But now all of my designators are upside down:
[image]

I don't like this. I figured out how to use the `Find Similar Objects` function to select all the designators in the room, but `Rotate Selection` does nothing to them.

Any ideas, besides individually rotating 14 designators? I'll have to reposition them anyway, but at least if I could rotate them in one shot, that would be something.

Comment: You can select the designators all at once using the tool and then rotate them 180 degrees. I am on the phone but there are lot of tutorials for multiple selection on Altium available online.

Comment: You can also just rotate the entire room with everything in it. Seems much easier to me tbh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get them selected then you can change their rotation parameter using the PCB inspector. You would have to do the horizontal and vertical ones seperately though.

Given you are planning to reposition them manually anyway i'm not convinced that this will save much time over just hitting space to rotate them while you are dragging them into place.

Comment: "If you can get them selected" --> PCB Filter. InComponentClass or ComponentClass (not at my Altium Computer right now) for the room and all kinds of other options available for fast selection.

Comment: Use the filter to select all designators that are on the top side and oriented at 180 (for example), then change them all to 0. Similarly, take all the ones oriented at 270 and change them to 90 (assuming you like 90 better than 270).

Comment: Good point on using the space bar as I moved each designator - this did end up being a better solution.